# How to parse elements of nested json object?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have a json object returned from an elasticsearch query as follows:

```
'took': 66, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 
'hits': {'total': {'value': 371, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}, 'aggregations': {'council_response': {'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0, 'sum_other_doc_count': 19, 'buckets': [{'key': 'Yes', 'doc_count': 86}, {'key': 'Refused', 'doc_count': 70}, {'key': 'no status available', 'doc_count': 68}, {'key': 'No', 'doc_count': 51}, {'key': 'Publicly available', 'doc_count': 26}, {'key': 'No Reply', 'doc_count': 13}, {'key': 'No ', 'doc_count': 12}, {'key': 'No reply', 'doc_count': 10}, {'key': 'Sort of', 'doc_count': 9}, {'key': 'Some stuff', 'doc_count': 7}]}}}
```

I would like to extract the doc count for each of the keys, so I have Yes - doc_count_number (Yes 86) and so on.

I have narrowed it down to:

```
[{'key': 'Yes', 'doc_count': 86}, {'key': 'Refused', 'doc_count': 70}, {'key': 'no status available', 'doc_count': 68}, {'key': 'No', 'doc_count': 51}, {'key': 'Publicly available', 'doc_count': 26}, {'key': 'No Reply', 'doc_count': 13}, {'key': 'No ', 'doc_count': 12}, {'key': 'No reply', 'doc_count': 10}, {'key': 'Sort of', 'doc_count': 9}, {'key': 'Some stuff', 'doc_count': 7}]
```

with `print(result['aggregations']['council_response']['buckets'])` but I can get no further. I have tried

`print(result['aggregations']['council_response']['buckets']['key']['Yes']['doc_count'])`

which gives the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
How can I make the last step to get the items I need?

```
buckets = result['aggregations']['council_response']['buckets']
filter(lambda d: d['key'] in ['Yes', 'yes'], buckets)
print(buckets)
```

produces exactly the same json object as the  shorter one above and if I do this `print(filter(lambda d: d['key'] in ['Yes', 'yes'], buckets))` I get: `<filter object at 0x7f7a380e3d90>`

Comment: Use Gson library from Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
buckets = result['aggregations']['council_response']['buckets']
list(filter(lambda d: d['key'] in ['Yes', 'yes'], buckets))[0]['doc_count']
```

Comment: thanks, it does not work. I will update my question to show you.

Comment: In what format would you like the results to be printed out? Can you update your question with the expected result?

Comment: nothing is returned with your most recent suggestion. I want to be able to do this: yes_count = result['aggregations']['council_response'] etc. 
no = relevant python code then I will put them into a dictionary and pass to a Flask jinja template for display in an html page.

Comment: with my latest update, I get 86 as a result, which is the count of the `Yes` bucket.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I am not explaining myself clearly. I would like to be able to write a line of code which goes Yes = result['aggregations']['council_response']etc. and then this variable can be passed to a dictionary which is {"Yes": yes} that I can later pass to an HTML page.

Comment: Now working, sorry my mistake. Thank you for your help!